# Issue with function calculating wrong answers when asked to process vector inputs vs. stand alone user inputs

Tags: r, function, if-statement, trigonometry, bearing

## Function Overview

I have created a function to calculate directional changes between consequetive bearings (which was calculated from my latitude and longitude data).

The bearings are always relative to the North-South line (i.e., number of degrees away from north), and thus in parallel to one another and are ethier positive (0 -> +180) or negitive (0 -> -180). I have accounted for the signs (positive or negitive) and the 'magnitude' (>90 or <90) of the bearings which has allowed me to create 'rules' using basic trig to calculate directional changes.

The function evaluates two consequtive bearings (i.e., A --- TO --- B), classifies thier direction (positive or negitive) and the bearing values (>90 or <90). It uses these classifications to determine which 'rule' to use and then calculates directional change using the calculation associated with that rule. See the function below:

### The Function

```
analyzeGPS_DirectionChange <- function(bearingVec1, bearingVec2) {

  a1 <- ifelse (bearingVec1 >= 0.00, "positive", "negitive")
  a2 <- ifelse (bearingVec2 >= 0.00, "positive", "negitive")
  Bearing_Signs <- paste(a1, a2)

  b1 <- ifelse (abs(bearingVec1) < 90.00, "less", "greater")
  b2 <- ifelse (abs(bearingVec2) < 90.00, "less", "greater")
  Bearing_Values <- paste(b1, b2)

  print(Bearing_Signs)
  print(Bearing_Values)

  if (Bearing_Signs == "positive positive" && Bearing_Values == "less less") {
      Direction_Change <- (90 - bearingVec1) + (90 + bearingVec2)
      } else if (Bearing_Signs == "positive positive" && Bearing_Values == "less greater") {
      Direction_Change <- (180 - bearingVec2) + bearingVec1
      } else if (Bearing_Signs == "positive positive" && Bearing_Values == "greater less") {
      Direction_Change <- 180 - ((bearingVec1 - 90) + (90 - bearingVec2))
      } else if (Bearing_Signs == "positive positive" && Bearing_Values == "greater greater") {
      Direction_Change <- (bearingVec1 - 90) + (180 - bearingVec2) + 90 
  }

  if (Bearing_Signs == "positive negitive" && Bearing_Values == "less less") {
      Direction_Change <- 180 - (abs(bearingVec2) + bearingVec1)
      } else if (Bearing_Signs == "positive negitive" && Bearing_Values == "less greater") {
      Direction_Change <- 180 - (90 + (90 - bearingVec1) + (180 - abs(bearingVec2)))
      } else if (Bearing_Signs == "positive negitive" && Bearing_Values == "greater less") {
      Direction_Change <- 90 - ((bearingVec1 - 90) + abs(bearingVec2))
      } else if (Bearing_Signs == "positive negitive" && Bearing_Values == "greater greater")  {
      Direction_Change <- 180 - ((180 - bearingVec1) + (180 - abs(bearingVec2)))
  }

  if (Bearing_Signs == "negitive positive" && Bearing_Values == "less less") {
      Direction_Change <- 180 - (abs(bearingVec1) + bearingVec2)
      } else if (Bearing_Signs == "negitive positive" && Bearing_Values == "less greater") {
      Direction_Change <- 180 - (90 + (90 - abs(bearingVec1)) + (180 - bearingVec2))
      } else if (Bearing_Signs == "negitive positive" && Bearing_Values == "greater less") {
      Direction_Change <- 90 - ((abs(bearingVec1) - 90) + bearingVec2)
      } else if (Bearing_Signs == "negitive positive" && Bearing_Values == "greater greater")  {
      Direction_Change <- 180 - ((180 - abs(bearingVec1)) + (180 - bearingVec2))
  }

  if (Bearing_Signs == "negitive negitive" && Bearing_Values == "less less") {
      Direction_Change <- (90 - abs(bearingVec2)) + (90 + abs(bearingVec1))
      } else if (Bearing_Signs == "negitive negitive" && Bearing_Values == "less greater") {
      Direction_Change <- (180 - abs(bearingVec2)) + abs(bearingVec1)
      } else if (Bearing_Signs == "negitive negitive" && Bearing_Values == "greater less") {
      Direction_Change <- (180 - abs(bearingVec1)) + abs(bearingVec2)
      } else if (Bearing_Signs == "negitive negitive" && Bearing_Values == "greater greater")  {
      Direction_Change <- (abs(bearingVec1) - 90) + 90 + (180 - abs(bearingVec2))
  }

 return(Direction_Change)

}
```

#### Issue

When I use the function, it evaluates the bearing inputs correctely (I have included the print statements so that you can easily assess this). See below the working example (I checked it and others manually by hand to double check the math and assignment ect...)

```
analyzeGPS_DirectionChange(bearingVec1 = 100.6587, bearingVec2 = 24.66356)

[1] "positive positive"
[1] "greater less"
[1] 104.0049
```

However, when I run two vectors through the function which represent consequtive points some are calculated correctly and others are errors. See below for example:

```
bearingVec1 <- c(1.988956, 100.658682, 24.663563, 122.423408, -30.556419, 14.702280, -74.235212, -5.619550, 78.729953, -135.463404, -2.600200)
bearingVec2 <- c(100.658682, 24.663563, 122.423408, -30.556419, 14.702280, -74.235212, -5.619550, 78.729953, -135.463404, -2.600200, -6.733987)

analyzeGPS_DirectionChange(bearingVec1, bearingVec2)

 [1] "positive positive" "positive positive" "positive positive" "positive negitive" "negitive positive" "positive negitive"
 [7] "negitive negitive" "negitive positive" "positive negitive" "negitive negitive" "negitive negitive"
 [1] "less greater" "greater less" "less greater" "greater less" "less less"    "less less"    "less less"    "less less"   
 [9] "less greater" "greater less" "less less"   
 [1]  81.33027 255.99512  82.24015 332.97983 134.74130 268.93749 111.38434  95.65050 394.19336  47.13680 184.13379
```

At first sight it seems to have worked, however there are a few errors in the actual value answers, see the first example above which calculated correctly when I entered the bearing values manually - those numbers correspond to bearingVec1[2] and bearingVec2[2] in the sample data I provided.

I do not know why it is incorrectly calculating when I provide the function with vectors. Please help me solve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from `if` in combination with `&&`. From the help of  `&&`

> ‘&’ and ‘&&’ indicate logical AND and ‘|’ and ‘||’ indicate
>        logical OR.  The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in
>        much the same way as arithmetic operators.  The longer form
>        evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each
>        vector.

That is your `if` clause will always fall back to the first element. Not what you want.

`ifelse` on the other hand is vectorized. So you could either replace all your if clauses by `ifelse` constructs, which may become very tricky given all your nested `ifs`.

Another solution would be to use any form of loop to pass only single values to your function. This approach is however, not very elegant and you are not fully exploiting the builtin capabilities of R to deal with vectors and may be significantly slower than rewriting your function to deal with vectors properly, but you can readily use your function:

```
 purrr::map2_dbl(bearingVec1, bearingVec2, analyzeGPS_DirectionChange)
 # [1]  81.33027 104.00488  82.24016  27.02017 134.74130  91.06251 248.61566
 # [8]  95.65050  34.19336  47.13680 175.86621
```

Another option is to use `Vectorize` which vectorizes your function (basically by doing a `mapply` under the hood):

```
 Vectorize(analyzeGPS_DirectionChange)(bearingVec1, bearingVec2)
 # [1]  81.33027 104.00488  82.24016  27.02017 134.74130  91.06251 248.61566
 # [8]  95.65050  34.19336  47.13680 175.86621
```

Comment: thank you for your help! It worked and I understand now, appreciate your time!